# Strange behavior when using JFileChooser

Tags: java

I've been making a Minesweeper clone in Java and everything has been going relatively well until I added support for saving and loading files. Saving and Loading the files works as intended, but the issue occurs when I load up the game, perform the initial click, and then exit. I'm presented with this error but it does not always occur:

> Exception while removing reference.

If I never declare JFileChooser in the constructor, I never get the error. When I do get the error, it never prints the stack trace either or any information regarding it.

```java
public class FileMenu extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 459585961076461945L;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private Path dir = Paths.get(".");
    private File file;
    private MineFrame frame;
    private JMenuItem easy, medium, hard,loadItem, exitItem, saveItem;
    private FileNameExtensionFilter filter;
    private JMenu menu, newGameMenu;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private FileDialog saveDialog;

    public FileMenu(MineFrame frame)
    {
        super();
        this.frame = frame;
        exitItem = new JMenuItem("Quit Game");
        saveItem = new JMenuItem("Save Game");
        loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load Game");

        easy = new JMenuItem("Beginner: 10 x 10. 10 Mines");
        medium = new JMenuItem("Intermdiate: 16 x 16. 40 Mines");
        hard = new JMenuItem("Expert: 16 x 30. 99 Mines");

        fileChooser = new JFileChooser(dir.toString());
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        newGameMenu = new JMenu("New Game");

        add(menu);
        menu.add(newGameMenu);
        menu.add(saveItem);
        menu.add(loadItem);
        menu.add(exitItem);

        newGameMenu.add(easy);
        newGameMenu.add(medium);
        newGameMenu.add(hard);

        easy.addActionListener(this);
        medium.addActionListener(this);
        hard.addActionListener(this);
        saveItem.addActionListener(this);  
        loadItem.addActionListener(this);
        exitItem.addActionListener(this);  
    }
```

This is the only location where the call to FileMenu() occurs

```java
public class MineFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4816731330494815932L;

    private MineBoard board;
    private JLabel mineLabel;
    private MinePanel minePanel;
    private JPanel fileBarPanel, mainPanel, labelPanel;
    private FileMenu menu;
    private BorderLayout layout;

    public MineFrame(MineBoard board)
    {
        super("Minesweeper Java");
        this.board = board;

        fileBarPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        labelPanel = new JPanel();
        menu = new FileMenu(this);
        layout = new BorderLayout();

        mineLabel = new JLabel();
        minePanel = new MinePanel(this);
        labelPanel.add(mineLabel);
        labelPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mineLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        mineLabel.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 20));
        fileBarPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        fileBarPanel.add(menu);
        minePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        mainPanel.add(fileBarPanel);
        mainPanel.add(labelPanel);

        setLayout(layout);
        add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(minePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(500,500);
    }
```

Interestingly enough, the error does not occur with FileDialog. I've searched google for it extensively and it's seemingly rare.

**UPDATE** Moving the object into the actionPerformed method did the trick somehow!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You'll probably need to create a minimal example. This thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873449/occasional-interruptedexception-when-quitting-a-swing-application and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367929/interruptedexception-using-filesystemview-without-other-swing-components seem to have the same issue. Usually when I use JFileChooser, I created it and display it at the same time. As your solution seems to suggest you did. Also, when you have an exception please include the whole exception.

Comment: @matt Thank you for the references, the strange thing is that was the exception in its entirety