# How do you stop a program from running in a blueprint class using a nested if statement and not a System.exit(0);?

Tags: java

In this code I tried to stop the program from running by using System.exit(0);

Is there a possible way to exit the program using a nested if statement and not using System.exit(0);

```
public String answerR1()
{
    if (answer .equals ("snow"))
    {
        message = "\nCorrect!";
    }
    else
    {
        message = "\nIncorrect!";
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return message;
}
public String answerR2()
{
    answer = answer.toLowerCase();
    if (answer .equals ("time"))
    {
        message = "\nCorrect!";
    }
    else
    {
        message = "\nIncorrect!";
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return message;
}
public String answerR3()
{
    if (answers == 20)
    {
        message = "\nCorrect!";
    }
    else
    {
        message = "\nIncorrect!";
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return message;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "stop the program".

Comment: @GeorgeZ. How much uncertainty is there when it comes to exiting a program?

Comment: @TylerH What other ways exist than `System#exit`?

Comment: @TylerH For some reason i think he just wants to "interrupt" method's flow, returning "" value or something.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. I haven't written Java since 9th grade so I have no clue; it seems clear though that OP is asking for ways other than System.exit(0) to exit his program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.exit(0) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651210/system-exit0-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternatives to System.exit(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790/alternatives-to-system-exit1)

Comment: I mean like exit the program

Comment: If you truly intend to exit the program, then there's nothing wrong with `System.exit(0)`.  Why are you seeking an alternative?

Answer (score -2):

```
    public String answerR1()
{
    if (answer .equals ("snow"))
    {
        message = "\nCorrect!";
    }
    else
    {
        message = "\nIncorrect!";
        //System.exit(0);
        break;
    }
    return message;
}
public String answerR2()
{
    answer = answer.toLowerCase();
    if (answer .equals ("time"))
    {
        message = "\nCorrect!";
    }
    else
    {
        message = "\nIncorrect!";
        //System.exit(0);
        break;
    }
    return message;
}
public String answerR3()
{
    if (answers == 20)
    {
        message = "\nCorrect!";
    }
    else
    {
        message = "\nIncorrect!";
        //System.exit(0);
        break;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Try to use Break instead of System.exit(0);

Comment: Did you test this?